# JList with JSeparator

Tags: java, jlist

I am trying to add a Seperator to my list and was able to by updating my custom `ListCellRenderer`.

However, the separator seems to take up an entire list index spot.

Any ideas how to stop this from occuring?

```
 public class SelectedListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
 @Override
 public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    String str = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    if ( str.equals("seperator"))
    {
        JSeparator sep = new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL);
        return sep;
    }
    //Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    if (isSelected) {
         setForeground(new Color(94, 94, 94) );
         setBackground(new Color(177, 214, 240) );
    }
    else
    {
         setBackground(list.getBackground());
         setForeground(new Color(94, 94, 94) );
    }
    setFont(list.getFont());   
    setText(str);
    return this;
 }
```

}

Comment: show us some example code.

Comment: Have a look at something like [this](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/jcombobox_items_with_separators), it might give you some ideas